# How to use bloomfilters with Ruby's Redis client

Tags: ruby, redis, bloom-filter

All of the ruby libraries that exist are doing a custom bloomfilter implementation. I want to use Redis's native bloomfilter functionality.

Is there a way to send manual commands to redis using the ruby client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it by calling those methods manually. For example:

```
client.call("BF.ADD", bloom_filter_name, key)
```

```
client.call("BF.EXISTS", bloom_filter_name, key)
```

##### Note

- You need to enable the bloom filter module. It doesn't come by default.
- AFAIK, it appears that you can only use the bloom filter (or cuckoo filter) module if you pay for Redis Enterprise.
- The code for the bloom filter (or cuckoo) filter that you might find online are community projects
- Any links to download the module are dead links.

I would love to be wrong about the above caveats!